# React Hook must be called in the exact same order BUT I got an exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've already understood "React Hook must be called in the exact same order."

So I think in following case it might be an error

```
export default function(onClick) {
    if (typeof onClick !== "function") {
        return;
    }
    const element = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (element.current) {
            element.current.addEventListener("click", onClick);
            element.current.style.cursor = "pointer";
        }
        return () => {
            if (element.current) {
                element.current.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
            }
        };
    }, []);
    return element;
}
```

But this code works! I don't know why... And I have other one, this is driving me crazy.

Look at this case:

```
export default function onClick(onClick) {
    if (typeof onClick !== "function") {
        return;
    }
    const element = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (element.current) {
            element.current.addEventListener("click", onClick);
            element.current.style.cursor = "pointer";
        }
        return () => {
            if (element.current) {
                element.current.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
            }
        };
    }, []);
    return element;
}
```

I just named function and It give an error to me...

Please let me know why upper case's hook is not an error?

---

I got it!

It is just ES-lint's bug

cf)https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19155

Comment: Try change the component name to `OnClick`, component's name should use pascal casing

Comment: I tried but It still sending an error...

Comment: I don't understand what error you're getting.  I think you have to show the error message and more of your code to diagnose your problem.  Is this supposed to be a component?  Shouldn't you be returning DOM?

Comment: my error message is just 
  Line 13:18:  React Hook "useRef" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?     react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
and I know why this is an error
I just want to know how is it working when I exported hook with anonymous function 
Like first case

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of if block..

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. You can follow the documentation here.

```
export default function(onClick) {
    
    const element = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (element.current) {
            element.current.addEventListener("click", onClick);
            element.current.style.cursor = "pointer";
        }
        return () => {
            if (element.current) {
                element.current.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
            }
        };
    }, []);
    return element;

if (typeof onClick !== "function") {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok I will.. thanks..!! :) but my question is case in anonymous function!

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand the question..

Comment: Only Call Hooks from React Functions
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same warning. It was because I had a condition similar to yours:

```
if (typeof onClick !== "function") {
  return;
}
```

above the hook.

Because of this condition, the hook will not run ***every*** time. That's where the warning is coming from.
I moved my condition after the hook and now everything is fine.